# The name for back-slash PSQL commands and the location of their help documentation?

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to copy a local CSV file to a remote postgresql server.

The regular copy command is clearly documented, one just types '\h copy' in the psql interactive shell.

I found out that the regular command works with files that are resident on the server and that I needed to use the back-slash copy version. The article that helped me was; "Loading Data Into vPostgres Databases Using psql \COPY" http://pubs.vmware.com/datadirector/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.datadirector.vpostgres.doc%2Fpg_supp_Getting_Started.5.5.html

Then I found the documentation to list all the backslash commands in another blog: 
"Postgresql - How to list the Postgresql slash commands | postgres command | alvinalexander.com" 
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/postgresql/list-postgresql-slash-commands

How do I list the help for the backslash commands? The syntax required was different.

Maybe they are called something special, ie not 'command'?

Maybe I was misinterpreting and there are backslash commands for every regular command?

I'm confused! Thank you so much!

Comment: If in doubt just look at the official manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html  And for the question: "*How do I list the help for the backslash commands?*" just read the introduction message after you started `psql`.

Comment: I see!  It says they are 'Meta-Commands.' Can I get that help info from within the shell?

Comment: When I typed '\? \copy' it didn't take the argument, it just lists the meta-commands, not the help for that one?

Comment: It doesn't give me the arguments to pass. '\?' returns the listings of many other commands and then: 'Copy  \copy ...      perform SQL COPY with data stream to the client host'. 
Is it perhaps a problem my version of psql/postgresql is older than yours?

Comment: The complete description of each command is only available in the manual - but you have a bookmark for that anyway, right?

Comment: ok, great, ty for the answer! would you like to repost as answer and I will check as answered? thank you so much, you are so speedy :).

Answer (score 1):

As @a_horse_with_no_name described, full help for \copy is not available inline with a command. Instead, go to the very long documentation home page, and search for the string \copy to find it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html